# An error when install cutorch in Torch7 with LuaRocks install in Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: lua, ubuntu-14.04, torch

i`m new to lua, and these days i just have installing the torch-7, when i install the cutorch an error happened :

```
weigq@weigq-Lenovo-G410:~/torch$ luarocks install cutorch
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
正克隆到 'cutorch'...
remote: Counting objects: 203, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (158/158), done.
remote: Total 203 (delta 57), reused 86 (delta 43), pack-reused 0
接收对象中: 100% (203/203), 191.70 KiB | 185.00 KiB/s, done.
处理 delta 中: 100% (57/57), done.
检查连接... 完成。
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/weigq/torch/install/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/weigq/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/cutorch/scm-1" && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) install

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Torch7 in /home/weigq/torch/install
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:548 (message):
  Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8668/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

i don`t know how to deal with it ? 
anyone can help me solve it,thanks!

Comment: Do You have CUDA drivers installed? Which ones specifically? Have You set up the search paths for those CUDA drivers and whole toolkit?

Comment: i just find that the graphics card of the computer which i used in lab is AMD! sad

Comment: So, probably You could try something like... [cltorch  (Torch OpenCL backend)](https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch). Or some another framework which does support OpenCL.

Comment: but can torch run with what you advise?

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but it's worth a try. It should, depending on Your video card.

Comment: thanks ,i`ll take a try

Answer (score -1):

Make sure You're using NVidia graphic card and do have driver and CUDA toolkit set-up.

```
$ lspci  | grep -i 'vga\|3d\|2d'
```

Should print the information about video card installed into Your machine.

If it's not NVidia and/or it only supports OpenCL, You could try [cltorch (Torch OpenCL backend)](https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch) or some another lower level framework, which does support OpenCL.

Btw, setting up the CUDA toolkit includes downloading and installing it from [the official site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and setting up the search paths (accordingly to your installation method). Example from [CUDA quick guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/secure/prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf):

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```